# Can't Install New Relic in my app

Tags: eclipse, newrelic

I have already installed New Relic 3. I followed the steps on the website. However, I always encounter this error when I right click my project and Install New Relic.

[image]

What might be the problem in my project? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions issue on the project folder. Make sure that you have full permissions/rights to read/write/execute on the project folder and the error should no longer appear. Similar messages can also appear if the project folder was moved and eclipse was not updated to reference the new location.